# como solucionar error Attempted to load class \"Configuration\" en symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony2

Buen día.
Estoy tratando de integrar el api docusign para firmar documentos digitalmente. Estoy siguiendo los pasos para su integracion (los pasos están aquí https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview ), pero me estanque en la parte donde debo inicializar la configuracion, la clase ya existe en el proyecto (ya lo verifique), pero aun asi me sale este error:

> Attempted to load class \"Configuration\" from namespace
>   \"DocuSign\eSign\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement.

Ya declare `use DocuSign\eSign\Configuration;` pero nada aun.No se que me salte o no hice. De antemano gracias.

```
    $username = "[USERNAME]";
    $password = "[PASSWORD]";
    $integrator_key = "[INTEGRATOR_KEY]";
    $host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
    $config = new Configuration(); -> en esta linea me da el fallo
```

Comment: Hola, para que podamos ayudarte mejor, podrías poner un trozo de tú código? así podemos mirar mejor el posible fallo

Comment: podrías probar usando algo así: `$config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();` y eliminando el use. Puede ser que estén pisándose algunas clases

Comment: Lo intente asi "$config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();" pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Inténtalo con `$config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();` con una contrabarra al inicio del namespace y cuéntanos.

Comment: La solucion fue colocar el path completo del autoload de docusing

Comment: Tengo una problema parecido me sale el mismo error con otra librería, De pronto puedes colocar el código con el que lo solucionaste? otra pregunta pusiste la librería dentro del Bundle o donde?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el OP ha indicado que ya ha solucionado el problema

Comment: @Joacer eso no tiene nada que ver. Genial si el OP ha resuelto el problema por su lado, pero eso no significa que la pregunta ya no sea útil en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante definir la solución a este problema de manera general.
Lo realice en Symfony 3.2.x

1.- Primero instalar la biblioteca en autoload.
En mi caso en  agregué mi biblioteca en composer.json:

```
 "Autoload": {
     "Psr-4": {"": "src /"},
     "Classmap": ["app / AppKernel.php", "app / AppCache.php", "** src / AppBundle / juanitourquiza / pagopayphone / library" **]
```

Y después de esta instrucción:

```
 composer update
```

2.- Cree un servicio para utilizar la inyección de dependencia dentro de mi bundle dentro de la carpeta Services que también cree para que este todo mas ordenado con el siguiente código:

```
//AppBundle/Services/PagotarjetaService.php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use BackendBundle\Entity\Reservation;
use AppBundle\juanitourquiza\pagopayphone\library;

class PagotarjetaService{

 public $manager;

 public function __construct($manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
 }

 public function implementacion(){
    //tu codigo va aqui
    die("prueba");
 }
}
```

3.- Se debe agregar en el config.yml las siguientes lineas:

```
//app/services.yml
services:
#service_name:
#    class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#    arguments: ['@another_service_name', 'plain_value', '%parameter_name%']

app.pagotarjeta_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\PagotarjetaService
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

4.- En el controlador que se lo vaya a utilizar se llama al servicio

```
use AppBundle\Services\PagotarjetaService;
```

5.- Finalmente hacemos uso del servicio en el controlador

```
$datospago=$this->get('app.pagotarjeta_service');
$datospago->implementacion();
```

6.- La salida para el ejemplo sera tu código, en este caso pusimos el texto **prueba** y eso se mostrara.

```
prueba
```

Espero les ayude, con esto se corrige este error y es la forma adecuada de implementarlo como servicio.

Saludos